# Checking a specific uri in the current url - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, uri

I am trying to check if the current url

```
base_url/index.php?name0=value0&name1=value1&name2=value2...
```

contains a specific `name=value`. I tried this

```
var path = $.inArray('name=value', $(location).attr('href').split('&'));
        if (path  > -1){ triggers my function...}
```

But I guess that this wouldn't work if the url is url encoded. Is there a way to check if the url contains `name=value` without checking all the conditions `(split('&')` or `split('%26'))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split will always work, because `&` part of url is not encoded if it split parameters. However, you can have name or value encoded in the url. To search for them, you should use `encodeURI` like that:

```
var path = $.inArray(encodeURI('name=value'), $(location).attr('href').split('&'));
    if (path  > -1){ triggers my function...}
```

Comment: That's not a part of JQuery, it's part of native browser javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use core javascript for this:

```
var parameterName = 'name0';
var parameterValue = 'value0';
var path = decodeURI(location.href).indexOf(parameterName+'='+parameterValue); 
if (path > -1){ 
    triggers my function...
}
```

**EDIT:** I've tested it more and neither solution is perfect: mine fails when you have something before the specified name value, for example: `varname0` when you check `name0` will be found and that's not correct, yours (and monshq's) doesn't check the first value/pair which follows `?` character.

[How can I get query string values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values) is something you're looking for.